# javascript date reference or value

Tags: javascript

I'm storing a date in a global variable called `MyDate`. If I write this:

```
var TheDate = MyDate;

for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
   TheDate = TheDate - i;
}
```

Am I just changing `TheDate` or am I also changing `MyDate`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only change TheDate.

see this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/VrcRG/)

This is because when you do `TheDate = TheDate - i` TheDate is no more treated as Date object but instead is long.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are by reference so it will change both of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check it

```
var TheDate = MyDate;
for (var i = 5; i > 0; i--) 
{
   TheDate = TheDate - i;
   alert("TheDate = " + TheDate);
   alert("MyDate = " + MyDate);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if `MyDate` is a Object: yes, if is a scalar: no